# maxLine já setado porém pula linha

Tags: android

Sei que se utilizar o TextView nativo do android e setar o `android:maxLines="1"` ele não deixa o usuário pular linha.

Porém estou utilizando os Textviews do `<com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText`:

- https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

Porém coloco o `maxLines="1"` e não funciona.

Minha dúvida é que nesse contexto o `maxLine` não funciona. O problema seria por causa da biblioteca que não aceita ?

```
<com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
    android:id="@+id/rua"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/rualHintCadastrarCliente"
    android:maxLines="1"
    app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
    app:met_iconLeft="@drawable/ic_person_pin_circle_black_24dp"
    app:met_iconPadding="11dp" />
```

[image: maxLine setado e pulando linha]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biblioteca utiliza:

```
app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
```